# How can I verify text in ControlType.Text in C# + TestStack.White?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, white-framework

How can I verify text in ControlType.Text using C# + TestStack.White?
I am just trying to verify that error message is correct and contains correct phrase.

I have tried different solutions:

1. TextBox errorTextBox = MainWindow.Get("txbError");
   Assert.AreEqual("User name or password is invalid", errorTextBox.Text);
2. TextBox errorTextBox = MainWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("User name or password is invalid"));
   Assert.AreEqual(errorTextBox.Text, "User name or password is invalid");

And others...

Always appears an error in VS:

> TestStack.White.AutomationException: Failed to get ControlType=edit,Name=User name or password is invalid

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7aPj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your login logic
...
var textBoxes = mainWindow.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Text));
foreach(Label textBox in textBoxes)
{
 if(textBox.Id.Contains("txbError"))
 {
  var actualError = textBox.Name.ToString();
  Assert.AreEqual(actualError, "Expected Error message");
 }
}
```